# How to make lists of tagged data in Google Sheets or Excel

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-sheets

I have created a google spreadsheet of tagged data (see example data below) and I am trying to make different lists based on the tags. For instance I would like to see a list of media, health, and eyes records. From the data below, there should be 4 results from health, 5 results for media, and 1 result for eyes. Note that a filter does not work for me because I would like to have 3 lists, each on separate tabs (not on the source data tab) that get updated when the source data gets updated. So if a new record with a health tag gets added, it should show up dynamically in the health tab. Is this even possible or do I need to create a macro?  I see that the new Google Sheets may have SQL like querying capabilities and this would work perfect in this case, but I have not had experience with it yet.

[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research I have found that the best functions for this are either "filter" or "query".  In this case I have chosen to use query:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$E$13,CONCATENATE("select A where I like '%",B1, "%'"))
```

This is a really powerful way to create tagged records and report on them later.  Thanks for all those who tried.

Answer (score 1):

Following function (for cell "F5" will work as you required.

```
=(countif(E5,"*" & B1 & "*"))>0
```

In this function, countif count a cell in range E5 which contains value of cell B1.

You can copy formula in cell F5 to cells F6 to End.